# Degree symbol missing with fourier-otf

Tags: fourier, degrees

I am currently writing my dissertation in TeX and am compiling with lualatex. I was intending to use the Utopia font as provided by the `fourier-otf` package. However, I noticed that the ° symbol does not display when using the `siunitx` package. Weirdly, ° prints just fine in text and also when using `\si{\celsius}`. It's just hidden when using the `\ang{}` command for angles. This bug does not happen when using the standard font and not loading `fourier-otf`. I don't have enough knowledge about latex fonts and combinations of latex packages to know what causes this or whether there are other packages that provide the same font without the bug. Does anyone know a workaround?

Here is a MWE:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fourier-otf}

\begin{document}
  This is a test. Degrees = °. It's 40 \si{\celsius} hot.

  \ang{47;56;68}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

As said before, I need the ° symbol also in the degree-minute-second coordinates.

Comment: Compiles fine for me using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: That's weird, maybe it's my texlive installation then or some missing dependencies / installed fonts? I am using LinuxMInt and the `texlive-full` distro from the official repositories. I can check later if I have this error also on other machines.

Comment: I tried on Overleaf with TeX Live 2021.

Comment: I confirm that your test file prints correctly on my installation (up to date TeXlive 2021, Debian), the three degrees symbols (U+00B0) are printed in the PDF file. The degrees symbol has been added to Erewhon-Math in version 0.42; the current one is 0.47,  I guess you have an old version of the Erewhon-Math package. You can check your version with `otfinfo -v \`kpsewhich Erewhon-Math.otf\``

Comment: @DanielFlipo You're correct! Your command shows my version is 0.41. How can I update?

Comment: If you're using latex from a linux dist, then you probably have to complain to the maitainers at the Linux dist. Sadly they are often behind on updates or does not update at all. The alternative is to use the UP stream TeXLive from `tug.org/texlive` but installing that on linux requires that you know what you're doing.

Comment: I agree with @daleif: the best thing to do would be to install TeXLive from https://tug.org/texlive/ (and then update it from time to time). Have a look at the documentation, it is pretty easy to install imho.

Comment: To solve the immediate problem you can download the latest version of the `.otf` file from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/erewhon-math and copy it to the same directory as your `.tex` file, then lualatex will use the new local file instead of the installed version.